# How come the override_dh_build-indep sequence isn't run by debuild?

Tags: packaging, debian

I'm having a bad time trying to generate some documentation for a shared library within `debian/rules`. I asked [a question earlier](https://askubuntu.com/questions/278746) about which target to use for generating the documentation.

My problem now is that the target `override_dh_build-indep` isn't being built when I run `debuild`. I inserted an `echo` statement at the top of the `%` target and discovered that `debuild` builds the following targets:

- `clean`
- `build`
- `install`

It would seem that `build-indep` isn't even being built. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is the source somewhere? Maybe try `override_dh_auto_build-indep`? You can play around and see what targets `dh` is actually running with `dh binary --no-act`

Comment: @andrewsomething: [Here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~george-edison55/nitroshare/nitroshare0.3-debian/files) are the Debian files.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled back on this question today. So I took the time to actually grab the code and figure this out. It seems like my comment above is correct. Use the `override_dh_auto_build-indep` target to build the docs.

This diff was able to produce a doc package with the doxygen generate docs building in a clean raring pbuilder.

```
=== added file 'debian/nitroshare-doc.install'
--- debian/nitroshare-doc.install   1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
+++ debian/nitroshare-doc.install   2013-07-01 18:29:50 +0000
@@ -0,0 +1,1 @@
+doc/* usr/share/doc/nitroshare-doc/

=== modified file 'debian/rules'
--- debian/rules    2013-07-01 18:07:18 +0000
+++ debian/rules    2013-07-01 18:09:03 +0000
@@ -7,3 +7,6 @@

 %:
    dh $@
+
+override_dh_auto_build-indep:
+   doxygen
```

Though this doesn't really answer your question, it does solve your problem...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `dh` source, it looks like behaviour changed here since compatibility level 9. Since then, I think `build` might correctly call `build-indep`. Try bumping `debian/compat` to 9 and bump your `debhelper` `Build-Depends` accordingly.